# Why is PHP not reading required file?

Tags: php

(I'm starting this question over from scratch. If you want to know what the original question was that MrMook attempted to answer, or the revised question that Progman commented on, see the edit history. I have now boiled down the behavior to the barest elements and ask the question anew based on that.)

I have created five files and their entire contents are as follows:

```
test-forward.php
    <?php
    require_once('script1.php');
    require_once('script2.php');
    ?>
test-backward.php
    <?php
    require_once('script2.php');
    require_once('script1.php');
    ?>
script1.php
    <?php
    SayHello()
    ?>
script2.php
    <?php
    function SayHello() {echo 'Hello';}
    ?>
test-together.php
    <?php
    SayHello();
    function SayHello() {echo 'Hello';}
    ?>
```

When I run either `test-backward.php` or `test-together.php`, the browser says `Hello`, and there is nothing added to PHP log file.

When I run `test-forward.php`, the browser is blank, and the PHP log file reports:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function SayHello() in ...\script1.php:2
```

The script `test-together.php` shows that a function can be called before it is defined. My understanding is (as MrMook said) that included (or required) scripts are all merged into the script that includes them before the whole thing is processed as one. But if that is true, then `test-forward.php` should behave the same as `test-together.php`, but it is not. Instead, it appears that in `test-forward.php`, `script2.php` is not being read.

The code above is the full contents of the five files, so you should be able to reproduce this behavior on your system. I'm running PHP 7.2 under Windows 7.

Why is `SayHello()` not defined when running `test-forward.php`?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is (now). When you have `require` or `include`, the source code will be read and executed. In one case you get a missing function error, in the other case you get a parse error (assuming the parse error is still in your script2.php file). Keep in mind that you have a `exit()` statement in your script1.php which terminates the php script. What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a script is loaded with `require` or `include` the content gets executed at the time when the `require` or `include` statement is called. When the script is trying to access a function which isn't defined (yet), you will get the generated error message.

Comment: Your answer agrees with what I said when I first asked the question (that it appears that first script1 is compiled, then script 1 is run, then script2 is compiled, then script2 is run), which disagrees with MrMook's answer and takes me back to the original question about documentation of the order in which scripts are processed, including both compiling and execution. The manual page for include() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) doesn't say anything about this.

Comment: @NewSites The first line in the documentation says "The include statement includes and evaluates the specified file.", so it does exactly that. The script is evaluated, which means it tries to call the function `SayHello()` which doesn't exists (yet). Therefore you get the error message.

Comment: Okay, I guess that's it. "Evaluate" is rather vague. I took it to mean parse and compile, but you're saying it includes execution. I wonder if my impression that execution came later comes from experience in another language? In any case, it looks like MrWook and I were both wrong about PHP working like that. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, note that the manual page for user-defined functions (http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) states, "Functions need not be defined before they are referenced, except when a function is conditionally defined". To that, should be added "and except when the definition is in an include()d or require()d file".

Answer (score 1):

PHP checks the executet file for requried files and just add the content of the required file into the executet file.
For Example if you execute `script0.php` which contains two `required_once`. It will first merge the content of both `required_once` into `script0.php` and then compile it.

So your executet file will be:

```
function1();
exit();
function function1() {}
```

Comment: It appears that this is incorrect. Please see the answer by Progman.

Comment: looks like it but it doesn't make a different because at the end it is the same. It will executed one after another because it is a script.

Comment: No, it makes a huge difference. A function definition can appear either before or after a call to that function, as long as they are in the same file. If they are in different included files, the definition must come before the call.