# Is the scope of functions (not variables) in included files different in Javascript and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, function, scope, jscript

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51692382/why-is-php-not-reading-required-file) last month about a problem in PHP calling a function in one include file that is defined in a later include file. This problem arose in converting an ASP site to PHP. I now see the problem happening again. It appears that Javascript and PHP handle function definitions in include files very differently.

(Edit: I'm talking here entirely about server-side scripts, nothing client-side.)

- In my ASP files (written in Javascript), I was able to call a function in an `#include`d file, when the function was defined in a file `#include`d after that one.
- In PHP, this does not work. It appears that a function must be defined in the same file or in a file `include()`d prior to one in which it is called.

This suggests a major difference in the operation of Javascript and PHP, which I have not found documented anywhere. It appears that Javascript compiles all included files before proceeding with execution, whereas PHP compiles and executes each include file before moving on to the next include file.

The PHP manual page on [user-defined functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) states, "Functions need not be defined before they are referenced, except when a function is conditionally defined". It appears that it should also say, "and except if the function is defined and called in different include files". The manual page for [include()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) also doesn't address this.

In Javascript, I had to think strategically about defining important variables in the earliest include files so they were available for use when needed, but functions could be defined in any include file and used whenever needed. But in PHP, it appears that I need to apply that kind of strategic thinking to where I define my functions as well.

It seems that if I'm right about what I've written here, this is a really significant difference between Javascript and PHP that should have been written about before. So am I wrong and have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Why do you expect totally different languages written by people who don't even know each other to work the exact same way? In Javascript there is absolutely no notion of "includes" files just like PHP, Javascript has a module system, PHP does not.

Comment: I don't expect the languages to be the same. I expect people who write about the differences to mention something important like this. And in Javascript, I'm talking about using `#include` to include files. I'm editing the question to show this.

Comment: There is no `#include` in Javascript. Show me in the Javascript specification where they talk about `#include`  https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/  . What people are you talking about? who is going to write about the differences? no, people expect you to learn different languages by reading their documentation, it's not up to third parties to highlight differences between language, it's up to you know come to these conclusions, nobody else.

Comment: *It appears that it should also say, "and except if the function is defined and called in different include files".* This is a fair point, the explanation should definitely be broader. The reason it doesn't work is for the same reason as [Example #2 on that page](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php). Functions defined in an included file are not available until run-time, whereas ones defined later in the same file are available from compile-time. Conditional function definitions are one example of this, but including/requiring files is another.

Comment: "my ASP files (written in Javascript)"...do you mean [Microsoft JScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript), which can be used serverside with ASP? That could use `#include` statements. **JavaScript** is the language executed client-side by the browser itself, and has no notion of an "include" statement. Two slightly different things, although originally based on the same language. Please take the time to ensure you understand and clearly identify what technology you are using / talking about - thanks.

Comment: @ADyson - You posted a comment with a link that looked interesting, but then it appears the comment has been deleted before I got to click on it. Can you post it again, please?

Comment: Might have been [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524876(v=vs.90).aspx). Just the docs on server-side includes in ASP. The same syntax is used whether you write your ASP code in JScript, VBScript or anything else. It says "ASP includes files before executing script commands. " - which is the key difference between ASP and PHP. PHP parses the script as it goes along, a file at a time, and "include" is just another command. So if you call a function before you include it, PHP will try to parse it before it gets to the include statement, and will decide it doesn't exist.

Comment: I would agree with you that PHP include() docs don't really make this very clear. Perhaps they thought it was obvious...but if you've come from a framework/language which works differently then it might not be. The PHP docs allow community contributions as you may have noticed, so you could always write something about it for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, PHP and Javascript differ a lot there.

In PHP, functions are a special kind of thing. Functions are global; if a function has been declared once *somewhere*, it is available to be called from *anywhere*. Declaring a function happens when a `function foo() ...` statement is being executed at runtime* (this is why *conditionally declared functions* are somewhat special). Functions have one global unique name; you cannot redeclare a function with the same name. Functions cannot be treated like ordinary values or variables, e.g. they can't be passed around.

* The confusing part here is that a `function ...` declaration may also be parsed and evaluated *at parse time*, the step immediately preceding runtime. In the parsing step, *non-conditional* function declarations are evaluated, leading to the functions being available at runtime "before they are declared". That of course doesn't work for anything that needs to be evaluated at runtime, like `include` statements.

---

In Javascript functions are just values assigned to variables. Functions have the same scoping rules as variables. Functions behave the same as ordinary values, e.g. they can be passed around like any other value. Functions are simply *callable* values.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. About PHP, when you say functions can be called from anywhere, that is except in an earlier include file. About Javascript, variables and functions behave very differently. I had to define variables before I used them, but that was not the case for functions.

Comment: Of course every language has its own intricacies and details and edge cases. I'm trying to answer very generically here, and what I say is correct. Yes, it is, even if I say so myself. It's hard to address any specific concerns without concrete examples. Taking a stab into the dark though: again, in PHP, an `include` statement needs to be executed at runtime, otherwise functions within the included file don't exist. As for Javascript, you may be talking about the specific case of *hoisting `function` declarations*, which doesn't negate anything about what I said.